# For infinite dimensional normed spaces, is the intersection of kernels of functionals infinite dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I was thinking of the following:

Suppose $f_{1},...,f_{n}$  are non-zero bounded linear functionals from a infinite dimensional normed space $X$. Then is $\cap_{i=1}^{n}\ker(f_{i})$ infinite dimensional?

I can see that this should be intuitively true but can someone comment on my attempt to prove it for general $n$? . For example, for the case of $n=1$, I can just take a vector $u\in X$ such that $f_{1}(u)=1$. Then $x=x-f(u)x+f(u)x$ which directly gives me that the kernel has codimension $1$ and hence is infinite dimensional.

But for the general case,

If I consider the map $T$, such that $x\mapsto(f_{1}(x),...,f_{n}(x))$ then this is a surjection onto a subspace of $\Bbb{K}^{n}$. As $\ker(T)=\cap_{i=1}^{n}\ker(f_{i})$ is closed, we have that $X/\cap_{i=1}^{n}\ker(f_{i})$ is well defined and it will have dimension $\leq n$. Hence $\cap_{i=1}^{n}\ker(f_{i})$ must be infinite dimensional as $X$ is infinite dimensional

Is the above okay?

Comment: Yes, that is a very nice proof, provided that you know that if $X$ is infinite-dimensional and $X/V$ finite-dimensional, then $V$ is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: All your topological considerations are off topic. This theorem is purely algebraic and is a corollary of the rank-nullity theorem: $\dim\ker T+\dim \operatorname{im}T=\dim X$ for every linear map defined on $X$ (even when $X$ is infinite-dimensional). Just apply this theorem to $T=(f_1,\dots,f_n):X\to\mathbb K^n.$ Note that $\mathbb K$ may be any field.

Comment: @AnneBauval I was in the context of normed spaces when I was doing this so I included it. Ofcourse we can quotient by any subspace and remove boundedness of linear funtionals. I'll edit it,

Comment: Btw if it is necessary then moderators can close this question as well to remove it from unanswered tag.